# sequence of positive numbers converging to a positive limit

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Suppose that {s$_n$} is a sequence of positive numbers converging to a positive limit.

Show that there is a positive number *c* so that s$_n$ > *c* for all *n*.

Comment: Have you any thoughts of your own on this?

Answer (score 1):

If $s_n \to s >0$, then by choosing $\epsilon = { s \over 2}$ you can find some $N$ such that $s_n \ge { s\over 2} > 0$ for all $n \ge N$.

What about $s_1,...,s_{N-1}$?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Let $l$ be the limit where the sequence $\{s_n\}$ converges.  As you have written $l>0$. Take $c = \frac{l}{2}$. Now apply the concept of covergence and show after some natural number $m$ all $\frac{3l}{2} > s_n > \frac{l}{2}$

Answer (score 1):

Let L = lim x(n) ===> For epsilon e = L/2, there is N > 0 such that if n > N ===> / x(n) - L / < L/2 ===> x(n) > L/2. By Archemedian principle for each x(k) with k = 1 to N, there is a positive integer m(k) > 0 such that m(k)*x(k) > L/2. Thus x(k) > L/(2*m(k)). Now let c = min{L/(2*m(1)), L/(2*m(2)),..., L/(2*m(N)} then c > 0, and x(n) > c for all n's.